# Magento 1.9.3 CE, Staging & Live Sites behave differently

Tags: magento1.9.3, staging

Lately, we found our Staging Site and Live Site behave differently in 2 situations:
1).  we found Live Site to have 500 error timeout while Staging Site is normal;
2).  we found update on CSS file in staging site reflected in frontend, while Live Site do not reflect the changes.

how to check the code difference, and how to sync the Staging site code to Live site?

THANKS FOR SHINING SOME LIGHT !  =:>

Answer (score 0):

you have to use github to create repository and track your code changes. repository for live server, one more for staging, and some branches for patches and fixes.

but you can check for example with `md5sum`:

live server:

```
find . -name "*\.php" -type f | xargs md5sum > checksum.md5
```

staging server:

```
md5sum -c checksum.md5  | grep -v OK
```

also `rsync` helps too, always use `-n` to `dry-run`

probably you have some webstack issues too.